# I get an error when i try deriving eq. How can i fix this?

Tags: haskell

I am getting this error:

- No instance for (Eq T1)
      arising from the first field of `TT' (type`Matrix T1')
    Possible fix:
      use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
        so you can specify the instance context yourself

  - When deriving the instance for (Eq TT)
    |
    20 |              } deriving (Eq, Ord)

and I don't know why and how I can fix this ( error is the same for Ord)

Here's my code:

```
import Data.Matrix
data T1 = T1 { x :: Char
             , y :: Int 
             , z :: Int 
             }
instance Show T1 where
    show t1 = [(x t1)] 

data TT = TT { myMap :: Matrix T1
             , flag :: Int
             } deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

In your example, a value of type `TT` contains a value of type `T1`; thus, to equate two values of type `TT`, you also need to know how to equate two values of type `T1`. But you haven't defined an `Eq` instance for `T1`! Add a `deriving (Eq)` clause to `T1` and the error will go away. The same applies to `Ord`.

In general, if you have a type `A`, which contains a value of type `B`, in order to derive a typeclass on `A`, you need to derive that same typeclass on `B`. As described above, this occurs because in order to implement the methods of that typeclass on `A`, you need to already know how that typeclass behaves on `B` e.g. you can't equate `A` values unless you know how `B` values are equal (which is your example above). Another example: if you want to show values of type `A` as a `String`, you need to be able to convert `B` to a string.

Comment: I added deriving (Eq, Ord) to T1 , Eq works fine but Ord has the same error

Comment: Does `Matrix` have an `Ord` instance?

Comment: Hmm...I don't think it has one. Ok.. so I must do it mannualy.